# Flux of a Vector Field (Surface Integrals)

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let S be the part of the plane 4x+2y+z=2 which lies in the first octant, oriented upward. Find the flux of the vector field F=1i+3j+1k across the surface S.

I ended up setting up the integral of ∫(0 to 2)∫(0 to 1/2-1/2y) 11 dxdy, but that turned out wrong.

What I did was start with changing the equation to z=2-4x-4y; the parametrics of these are x=x, y=y, z=2-4x-2y.

From there I got that delr/delx=<1,0,-4> and delr/dely=<0,1,-2>.

Taking that cross product I got <4,2,1>.

Then I put that into the integral of Flux=∫∫_s <1,3,1>(dot)<4,2,1>, with bounds 0<=y<=2 and 0<=x<=1/2-1/2y. This ended up being wrong.

Comment: Please use mathjax for your formulas and equations.

Answer (score 1):

The parametric representation of $S$ is
$$(x,y)\mapsto{\bf r}(x,y):=(x,y,2-4x-2y)$$
with triangular domain
$$D:=\bigl\{(x,y)\bigm|0\leq x\leq{1\over2}, \ 0\leq y\leq 1-2x\bigr\}\ .$$
The rest of your computation is correct. We have
$${\bf r}_x\times{\bf r}_y=(1,0,-4)\times(0,1,2)=(4,2,1)\ ,$$
which has the correct orientation, and therefore
$${\bf F}\cdot({\bf r}_x\times{\bf r}_y)\equiv(1,3,1)\cdot(4,2,1)=11\ .$$
It follows that the flux $\Phi$ is given by
$$\Phi=\int_S{\bf F}\cdot\>d\vec S=\int_D{\bf F}\cdot({\bf r}_x\times{\bf r}_y)\>{\rm d}(x,y)=11\> {\rm area}(D)={11\over4}\ .$$